# Assign a static variable before declaring

Tags: java, static

I'm learning Java and write the simple code below:

```
public class Test {

    private int a = b;  
    private final static int b = 10;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println(test.getA());
    }

}
```

**The result: 10**. Well done! It run successfully and have no error.

Can anyone please explain why I can assign a static variable before declaring it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what order are Java class variables initialised?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138801/in-what-order-are-java-class-variables-initialised)

Comment: static members are already initialized once class in loaded before creating any instance of it.

Comment: What do you mean with "assign before declaring"? "int b" declares, "= 10" assigns, so you declare before you assign. Or do you mean use before declare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment

```
private int a = b;
```

takes place when you create a new instance of `Test` (just before the constructor is called).

The declaration and initialization of the static variable `b`, takes place before the instance is created, when the class is loaded.

The order of the statements doesn't matter, since static variables are always initialized first.

Comment: "(just before the constructor is called)" not quite, initialization of fields is moved to constructors, so it is more like "when constructor is called, but after its implicit or explicit `super(arguments)` call".

Comment: Can you share any official document for me? I really like to understand deeply

Comment: @DatNguyen The most official doc is the JLS. Read sections [12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) and [12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Answer (score 1):

Javavariables are initialised this order:

1. Static variables of the superclasses if any
2. static variables of the current class.
3. Static variables, and static blocks in the order that they are
   declared
4. Instance variables of the superclasses
5. All instance variables of the current class.
6. Instance variables, and instance level initialisation blocks, in
   declaration order

Therefore "b" is intialized before the "a".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The order of declaring variables doesn't really matter in your code as in reality the static variable is going to be initialized before non-static ones.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are bound to a class - which of course always exists before instances of the class. Thus, you can freely assign it to instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote works well because
`private final static int b = 10;`
is a **class variable** (*static field*). Those type of variables are initialised for first.

Then is executed the line
`private int a = b;`
which initialise the **instance variable** (*field*) `a`.

In short, it doesn't matter the order in which those variables are declared in your code. *Class variables* are always declared before *instance variables*.